# How to isolate apps from the internet?

Tags: firewall

Can I completely isolate apps on mac from the internet, without installing any additional software ?

I need a sort of firewall to isolate them
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't without additional software. The only solution would be to cut the Internet connexion of your computer.

You can block incoming connexions though, using the standard Mac OS X Firewall (accessible in the Security & Privacy panel of the System Preferences). When activated, when an application wants to start listening on a certain port, you are prompted to allow or deny the listening.

With additional software, you can use the excellent [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) application that allows blocking outgoing connexions as well.